# Is there a comprehensive list of the Ubuntu web services for developers?

Tags: development

Canonical/Ubuntu provides many services for developers/users, but there doesn't seem to be a complete list of these services anywhere. These services help get people involved and help developers work on issues.

Comment: If there isn't a comprehensive list, perhaps this should be the place for the list. Adding a new answer below for each site that is found along with a brief description.

Comment: Just read your comment.  Should I split up my answer?

Comment: @EmersonHsieh, I've talked to the mods, mark your answer as a community wiki and all new answers we will just put there.

Comment: Made it a Community wiki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a few couple of Ubuntu services (or subdomains).  Not all of them is strictly developer-related:

**Ubuntu Pastebin** - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Official Ubuntu Pastebin

**Ubuntu Wiki** - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/

This may be obvious...

**Ubuntu Official Documentation** - http://help.ubuntu.com/

This may be more obvious...

**Ubuntu Brainstorm** - `http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/` <sup>shutdown</sup>

Submit your Idea for Ubuntu here

**Ubuntu Forums** - http://forums.ubuntu.com/

This leads to the Official Ubuntu Forums.

**Planet Ubuntu** - http://planet.ubuntu.com/

A blog for Ubuntu developers written by Ubuntu developers.

**Ubuntu App Developers** - http://developer.ubuntu.com/

A site for Developers that develop apps for Ubuntu.

**Ubuntu Mailing List** - https://lists.ubuntu.com/

You can subscribe stuff about Ubuntu here.

**Ubuntu Fridge** - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/

An Information Hub for the Ubuntu Community.

**Ubuntu Error Reports** - https://errors.ubuntu.com/

Error reports about Ubuntu goes here.

**Ubuntu Harvest** - `http://harvest.ubuntu.com/`<sup>shutdown</sup>

Harvest makes it easy to find low-hanging opportunities in Ubuntu. It aggregates the mass of todo lists we use every day so it's simple to find and coordinate work.

**Ubuntu Single Sign On** - http://login.ubuntu.com/

Manage your Ubuntu SSO account here.

**Ubuntu Status** - http://status.ubuntu.com/

This page shows the progress towards completing all of the Topics for the current cycle.

**Ubuntu Apps Directory** - https://apps.ubuntu.com

All apps in the Ubuntu Software Center

**Ubuntu Developer Summit** - http://uds.ubuntu.com/

UDS Official Website

**Ubuntu CD Images** - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com

All Ubuntu ISO's - From Warty to Quantal

**Ubuntu Packages** - http://packages.ubuntu.com

Information about Ubuntu's Packages.

Answer (score 2):

http://planet.ubuntu.com/ is the one i love to visit all the time :)